# Xamarin Firebase RTDB and permission denied 401

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, permission-denied

My db rules -

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

DB -

```json
{
  "Users" : {
    "aaaaaRfeyDVEjAfhpKEC2Vwxxxxx" : {
      "SendEmailId" : "xyz"
    },
    "bbbbbzOyj6QVZAg4pjaoqjqyyyyy" : {
      "SendEmailId" : "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

C# Code to access data

```cs
var dbNodePath = $@"Users/{_service.CurrentUserId()}"; 
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_service.CurrentUserId()); //this confirms the user Uid
FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://mydb-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app");
                
var db = (await firebase.Child("Users").Child("SendEmailId")
    .OnceSingleAsync<User>());
```

I get an exception with
RequestUrl set to - https://mydb-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/Users/SendEmailId/.json
ResponseData set to -

```
{
  "error" : "Permission denied"
}
```

StatusCode set to System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized

I googled the issue, most of the results suggest to change the rule to

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        **".write": true,
        ".read": true**
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which allows any user to access the db. With this option, code can read DB values.
The search results suggest to switch to this rule during development and to replace it with real rules during production.
This confuses me as to

1. when and how can I switch to production mode
2. when and how to test the real rules

Xamarin solution has 2 projects -

The android one uses following nugget pckgs -

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="FirebaseAdmin">
      <Version>2.2.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="FirebaseDatabase.net">
      <Version>4.0.6</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Auth">
      <Version>121.0.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Core">
      <Version>119.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2012" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.SafetyNet">
      <Version>117.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
```

The Xamarin forms uses following Nugget pckgs -

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="FirebaseAdmin" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FirebaseDatabase.net" Version="4.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2083" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.0" />
```

Any help is highly appreciable. As I do not have enough reputation to post comments on relevant stackoverflow qs/ans.

Answer (score 0):

> when and how can I switch to production mode

After your product has been tested with no problems, you can replace it with real rules during production.

> when and how to test the real rules

During this time, you can test with special users accout before you release it. This is the normal process for APP development.

Comment: Hello Jessie Zhang,
Thank you for the reply. 
Is there any documentation available on this?
e.g. How to setup the special user account? , How to develop newer ver of app when earlier version is in production?

Comment: `How to setup the special user account?` In other words, you can create test accounts to test your application until it is released.

Comment: `How to develop newer ver of app when earlier version is in production?` You can use version control and collaboration tools to control your project(e.g. `gitlab`).

Comment: Hello Jessie Zhang,
Thank you for the replies.
1. Is there any way to setup admin account?
2. For conde control off course Git is the way. I was talking about DB and rules in Firebase. Do we create another DB or another node in DB in the DB that is production released for testing?

Comment: `Is there any way to setup admin account?`  You can just create some test accounts for test only just as the way you create for other common accounts.